# What is the definition of "control input" in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm developing `uTensor` and the code generator for it, `utensor_cgen`.

https://github.com/uTensor/uTensor

https://github.com/uTensor/utensor_cgen

For the code generator, I have to parse a quantized `graph_def` protocolbuff file (the `pb file`).
However, I found that there are some input node not visible in `tensorboard` but visible in the `graph_def.node`.
Their name starts with a `^` and when I look into `tf.import_graph_def` source code, I found this `_IsControlInput` function:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py#L92

I really need to know the definition of "control input" so I can properly parse the pb file and convert it into a correct `uTensor` implementation targeting MCU.

Can somebody tell me where I can find the definition?
It seems like not found in the documentation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It might be related to control dependencies. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Graph#control_dependencies